# VK API повторение сообщений

Tags: php

Подскажите пример реализации random_id в моем случае для message.send чтобы сообщение 100500 раз не повторялось

```
    case "group_leave":
        $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
        $GetUserInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token={$token}&v=5.80"));
        $username = $GetUserInfo->response[0]->first_name;

        $request_params = array(
        'message' => "Расставаться всегда грустно, {$username}, но мы не прощаемся, а лишь говорим - До скорых, встреч !",
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => '5.80'
        );
 $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?';
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_params);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);       



        echo ('ok');
        break;
```

Достаточно ли будет написать в `$request_params` просто `"random_id" => "time()"` ?

Comment: Можете попробовать `"random_id" => rand().time()`, и вынесите из `switch` запрос `curl`. Сделайте отдельную функцию для этого.

Comment: Да, код побыстрому бросал, сейчас уже все по функциям ) Прописал `time()` и вроде все гладко пока..